# How to search for a partial string in a specific field in Azure Search?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have an index with a `title` field.  In it, I have the following text:  **Bakersfield Memorial Hospital**.

I would like to be able to search by a partial string.  The following queries works:

```
search=*&$filter=search.ismatch('bakersfield','title')
search=*&$filter=search.ismatch('memorial','title')
```

However, if I were to search on a partial string of the word, it doesn't.  For instance:

```
search=*&$filter=search.ismatch('baker','title')
```

So how do I search for partial word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question in case someone needs this.

You could use the `*` operator like this:

```
search=*&$filter=search.ismatch('baker*','title')
```

However, that only works for a *begins with* search.  It doesn't work for a contains or ends with.  For instance, the following doesn't work:

```
search=*&$filter=search.ismatch('*field','title')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example you use search.ismatch() without specifying the queryType. That means it will default to *simple* mode which only supports suffix wildcard.

- See [search.ismatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-full-text-search-functions#searchismatch) for info on how to enable full Lucene syntax.
- See [wildcard search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#bkmk_wildcard) for info on limitations on wildcards.

Example that matches "centre" and "center":

```
search=*&$filter=search.ismatch('medical cent*','title','full','all')
```

As explained in the wildcards link above you can't start a wildcard query with *, but you can use regular expression syntax in *full* mode. This should translate well to your use case.

Example that matches "senter" and "center":

```
search=*&$filter=search.ismatch('/.*enter/','title','full','all')
```